Show $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^k}-1}}dy=\sqrt\pi\frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+2}{2k})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{k})}$
I want to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y^k}-1}}dy=\sqrt\pi\frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+2}{2k})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{k})}$.
I already noticed that the rhs is very similar to the Beta-function (I am not sure exactly which one yet). However my ansatz was to simply try bringing the integral on the lhs in to the form of the Beta-function.
My first step was to substitute y=x^(-k). This gave me $\int_\infty^1 \frac{1}{k} {x}^\frac{1-k}{k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}-1}}dx$.
I dont know which step I should do next. The 1/k term also seems very odd.
Does anyone have some ideas for me for the next steps? Thanks!

Rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{y k}-1}} d y 
= \int_0^1 \frac{y^{\frac{k}{2}}}{\sqrt{1-y^k}} d y
$$
Letting $y=\sin ^{\frac{2}{k}}\theta$ transforms the integral into a Beta function and then Gamma functions.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \cdot \frac{2}{k} \sin ^{\frac{2}{k}-1} \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{2}{k} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{k+2}{2 k}\right)-1} \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{k} B\left(\frac{k+2}{2 k}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{k} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2 k}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}+1\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{k} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2 k}\right)}{\frac{1}{k} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac{k+2}{2 k}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)} \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

Note that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{y^k} - 1 }} dy = \int_{0}^{1} y^{k/2} (1-y^{k})^{-1/2} dy
$$
use $y = u^{1/k}$, with $dy = \frac{1}{k} u^{1/k - 1}$ and $y^{k} = u$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} y^{k/2} (1-y^{k})^{-1/2} dy & = \int_{0}^{1} u^{1/2}(1-u)^{-1/2}  \frac{1}{k} u^{1/k - 1} du \\
& = \frac{1}{k} \int_{0}^{1} u^{1/2+1/k - 1} (1-u)^{-1/2} du
\end{align*}
And the latter is known.

Pages 166 of Advanced calculus by Fredrick Woods covers integrals of this type. The integral with respect to u is Beta of (1/2+1/k,1/2) , Beta(a,b) = gamma(a)gamma(b)/gamma(a+b).
